# When loading multiple images from network requests, should I return the image data or a link to the image?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that lists local places in a table view. Each cell has a picture, text, and subtext. 
Each cell's detail view also has multiple pictures of the relevant location, as well as a decent amount of text. JSON is the interchange format.

Currently I am sending bit blobs and constructing it into a jpeg once loaded to the device but I am worried this is intensive on both the device and the server. So I was considering sending a link to the picture and asynchronously downloading each picture, but I am unaware of what repercussions this would have. Especially considering that I am currently using a cheap PHP/MySQL shared hosting plan for the backend.

I am looking for a list of pros and cons for sending the raw image data through JSON vs a link to that image. Any other options for quickly and efficiently populating a view with multiple network images is welcome.

Comment: Roughly how big are these pictures?

Comment: Currently around 200kb each but I'm about to change the layout and they will then be about 500kb or so.

Comment: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) seems to be helpful for this kind of thing, though it will require some tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a little bit of research into this and asked a few colleagues, so I'll share what tidbits I've come up with.

At some point, the raw image data is going to have to be sent- that is unavoidable. 
But I can benefit from lazily loading the image data- so that if my user only looks through 14 tableview cells, I only spend time loading 14 images instead of however many total results are returned from the server (And even less if I implement proper caching).

My solution so far is to return 30 (the number of tableview cells I load at one time) JSON objects, each having an `"Image_URL":"..."` field and putting those into a dictionary. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I check to see if the image for that cell is already cached and if not, I make a request for that picture and update the `cell.image` in the network callback.

This is pretty simple to do on your own, but [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) seems like a pretty good library for handling corner cases, caching, and other things that aren't covered in a basic implementation. I should note that [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) also includes functionality for asynchronous image downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is as following:

1- the user will download : (link+image > image) more data stream.

2- if the image is on another server -> might be slower than your server or faster -> affect the image loading speed provided for the user and minimize transmitted data size between your server and the client.

3- if the image is on another server -> do you guarantee that it will be there when your website is up ?

4- loading data using ajax is already an asynchronous method and you don't have to worry about another server if you use it. well, unless your server is as slow as hell then you should consider using another server for the big images as the synchronization won't be your major concern as it is the load you are applying to your server.

if other points come to my mind, I'll post them here ..